# M1 unexpected T_RETURN, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: magento-1.8, php

a have a problem after installing an extension.
I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN, expecting T_FUNCTION in blablalbala/Autoloader.php
```

the code in that file is this:

```
class Zitec_Emkp_Model_Observer_Autoloader extends Zitec_Integrator_Vendor_Autoload
{
    use Zitec_Emkp_Traits_Version;
}
```

help me get over it.
Thanks!

Comment: Your `return` statement needs to be inside the function

Comment: Are you sure the file you shown here has error?